# Remove contents of an array from a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to remove the contents of an array
`positions = ['CF','ST','RW','LW','CB','RB','LB','CM','CAM','CDM','RM','LM','RWB','LWB']`
from the column Name in my dataframe with football players.Sample of this dataframe below.
[Player dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKRYM.png)

Can anyone help me remove these strings, I have tried str.replace and it won't work,

Thanks

Comment: Did you use the `inplace` parameter when using str.replace

Comment: @MichaelMallon, can I ask what you used for benchmarking? I found jezrael's solution ~15x slower than mine..

Comment: But don't take my word.. please test and see what works for you!

Comment: @jpp Sorry I didn't see your answer both work well I have given you the correct answer as yours is faster after I benchmarked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below method matches specifically on space-separated values.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Player': ['ABC CF ST RW', 'DEF LB CM', 'GHI RM', 'JKL']})

rem = ['CF','ST','RW','LW','CB','RB','LB',
       'CM','CAM','CDM','RM','LM','RWB','LWB']

rem_set = set(rem)

def remover(p):
    return ' '.join([x for x in p.split() if x not in rem_set])

df['Player'] = df['Player'].map(remover)

#   Player
# 0    ABC
# 1    DEF
# 2    GHI
# 3    JKL
```

**Performance benchmarking**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Player': ['ABC CF ST RW', 'DEF LB CM', 'GHI RM', 'JKL']})

rem = ['CF','ST','RW','LW','CB','RB','LB',
       'CM','CAM','CDM','RM','LM','RWB','LWB']

rem_set = set(rem)

df = pd.concat([df]*20000)

def jez(df):
    d = {r'(\b){}(\b)'.format(x):r'' for x in rem_set}
    df['Player'] = df['Player'].replace(d, regex=True)
    return df

def jp(df):
    def remover(p):
        return ' '.join([x for x in p.split() if x not in rem_set])

    df['Player'] = df['Player'].map(remover)
    return df

%timeit jez(df)  # 1.24s
%timeit jp(df)   # 86ms
```

Answer (score 0):

I think need if is necessary remove all strings after last whitespace:

```
df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.rsplit(n=1).str[0]
```

Or if need remove values by `positions` only (with jpp DataFrame):

```
d = {r'\s+(\b){}(\b)'.format(x):r'' for x in positions}
df['Name'] = df['Name'].replace(d, regex=True)
print (df)
  Name
0  ABC
1  DEF
2  GHI
3  JKL
```

Comment: I like this solution as it's clean, but it seems to perform really poorly. Maybe something to do with `df.series.replace` again.

Answer (score 0):

You might find it enough to just remove all 2 or 3 character uppercase entries at the end as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    ['Name', 'Overall', 'Club'], 
    ['L. Messi CF ST RW', 94, 'FC Barcelona'],
    ['Cristiano Ronaldo LW LM ST RM', 92, 'Real Madrid CF']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0])    
df['Name'] = df['Name'].replace(r'((\s+[A-Z]{2,3}))+$', '', regex=True)

print(df)
```

This would give you:

```
                Name  Overall            Club
0           L. Messi       94    FC Barcelona
1  Cristiano Ronaldo       92  Real Madrid CF
```

Answer (score -1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Name": ["James kon CF ST RW", "Rom CAM"], "Overall": [23,65], "Club": ["a", "b"]})

positions = set(['CF','ST','RW','LW','CB','RB','LB','CM','CAM','CDM','RM','LM','RWB','LWB'])

def f(name, position):
    item = set(name.split(" "))
    newobj = item - position
    return " ".join(newobj)

df["Name"].map(lambda x: f(x, positions))
```